# Marble probability problem

Tags: probability

```
We have a bag with 4 red marbles and 9 blue marbles.
You draw three marbles out of the bag without replacement.

What is the probability that you got a red, blue, and red marble in that order?
```

Are these considered independent or conditional? Ive worked out red = 4/13 then blue 9/12 then red 3/11. Do I just multiply these together? If I did that would mean they are independent right?

Comment: Not independent, because every time you draw a marble, the next time you draw another, the conditions have changed.

Comment: @cagt I was thinking that because I had already drawn a marble making the condition change making the second draw conditional on the first draw..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've calculated the probability correctly:

$$P(RBR) = \frac{4}{13} \cdot \frac{3}{4}  \cdot \frac{3}{11} = \frac{9}{143}.$$

What @CAGT said about independence is correct (the draws aren't independent).  But this is consistent with what you've done.  The probability of drawing the second red one $(3/11)$ is different than that of drawing the first one $(4/13)$.